# What is the name of the assigned model?

Tags: model, terminology

When having some experimental data, one way to design a model presenting this data is as follows:

Given $f(x,y)$ with the following values 
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} 
\hline 
 x  & y & f \\ \hline
2 & 5 & 7 \\ \hline
2 & 6 & 6 \\ \hline
5 & 5 & 8 \\ \hline
5 & 6 & 10 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
then $\bar{f}=\frac{7+6+8+10}{4}=\frac{31}{4}$.

As it appears from the table, the variable $x$ has  $2$ levels $ 2$  and  $5$, and the variable $y$ has also two levels $5$  and  $6$. 
The representative model for $f$, designated $\hat{f}$  is defined by 
$$ \hat{f}= \bar{f} + \begin{bmatrix} Ix_1 & Ix_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} Ex_1 \\ Ex_2 \end{bmatrix}+  \begin{bmatrix} Iy_1 & Iy_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} Ey_1 \\ Ey_2 \end{bmatrix} $$

Where  $Ix_1$ is the indicator for $x$ at level one ( $2$), and defined as  $$Ix_1=\frac{x-5}{2-5}$$ 
Similarly the second indicator $$Ix_2=\frac{x-2}{5-2}$$ 
and  $Ex_1$ is the effect of  $x$ at level  one, defined as $$ Ex_1= \text{ mean of } f  \text{ when } x \text{ is at first level  } ( x=2)  - \bar{f} $$

Similarly for the second effect, and analogously the indicators and effects of  $y$  are calculated.

**My Question**: What is the name of such models? Are there some references related to such a model?

Indeed, I saw this model in a French book, and they called it as   "Modèle Matriciel", I googled aiming to better understand this model, however I failed even to find an associated reference.

Comment: Whether there is a model in evidence is obscure, because you only show some calculations.  However, they look remarkably like the well-known and commonplace [Analysis of Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance), or ANOVA.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment,  I agree that the general insight of this modeling has some common aspects as the ANOVA decomposintion(as the way the whole model is decomposed in  parameter dependent  functions).  However,  if we consider the case when a variable hs three levels then the indicator become $$ Ix=\frac{(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}{(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3}$$ this remindes me with the lagrangian intepolation. Moreover, here we have polynomials, unlike the case of ANOVA, where no restriction is on the form of the basis of decomposition. For that I was wondering if it has special name.